# no acceptable features were found on the selected site

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes

We have developed an Eclipse plugin and created an update site for IBM Notes 9. We have tested this plugin on several laptops/pc's, but on some machines we are getting the following error message:

No acceptable features were found on the selected site(s). Choose a different site or site category.

Help -> Support -> View Log / View Trace does not show any messages related to our plugin installation.

Any suggestions how to start debugging this issue? Is there a different log file / settings which gives us more insight on what might go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is running into a similar situation, we solved the problem as follows:

We Started the client in debug mode

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notes9\framework\rcp\rcplauncher.exe" -config notes -console
```

The console log showed us that a dependency, the jUnit plugin, was not available on the client. We moved the jUnit tests to a different project which was not included in our build.

Comment: Iam having a similar issue now. Trying to build a plugin. But when i install the update site i get the error. Cannot figure out whats going wrong. I have added the Junit jar in the build path aswell

Comment: Got the issue resolved. Root cause was when I was trying to intall a plugin the lotus was not able to remove the previously installed version of the plugin. So i had to manually delete the plugin and feature. Please follow the steps here : http://lekkimworld.com/2010/03/17/complete_guide_to_manually_uninstalling_plugins_from_lotus_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check if a plugin version is already installed. It may be because when you install the new version of the plugin the old version is not able to get deleted. you may manually delete the existing plugin by following the below steps:

http://lekkimworld.com/2010/03/17/complete_guide_to_manually_uninstalling_plugins_from_lotus_notes.html

I had a very similar issue and it worked for me. As mentioned above you may start the Lotus notes in debug mode to check aswell to see if any log files are missing.